# Python pandas stuck at version 0.7.0

Tags: python, pandas

First off, I'm a novice... I'm a newbie to Python, pandas, and Linux.

I'm getting some errors when trying to populate a DataFrame (sql.read_frame() gives an exception when trying to read from my MySQL DB, but I am able to execute and fetch a query / stored proc).  I noticed that pandas is at version 0.7.0, and running "sudo apt-get install python-pandas" just says that it's up to date (no errors): "... python-pandas is already the newest version. 0 upgraded..."

Based on some other posts I found on the web, I think my DataFrame problem may be due to the older version of pandas (something about a pandas bug involving tuples of tuples?).  Why won't pandas update to a more current version?

Setup:

```
Ubuntu: 12.04.2 LTS Desktop (virtual workstation on VMWare)
sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get upgrade, and sudo apt-get dist-upgrade all current
Python: 2.7.3 (default, April 10 2013, 06:20:15) /n [GCC 4.6.3] on Linux2
$ "which python" only show a single instance: /usr/bin/python
pandas.__version__ = 0.7.0
numpy.__version__ = 1.6.1
```

I tried installing Anaconda previously, but that turned into a big nightmare, with conflicting versions of Python.  I finally rolled back to previous VM snapshot and started over, installing all of the MySQL, pandas, and iPython using apt-get on the individual packages.

I'm not having any other problems on this workstation... apt-get seems to be working fine in general, and all other apps (MySQL Workbench, Kettle / spoon, etc.) are all working properly and up to date.

Any ideas why Python pandas won't upgrade to 0.11.0?  Thank you.

Comment: One more piece of information - from python:
import pandas
print(pandas)
output: "<module 'pandas' from '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/__init__.pyc'>

Comment: I reccommend giving Anaconda another go, it would be interesting to know what troubles you were facing with multiple python version, if you install pip via conda it usually does a pretty good job of segregating!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As nitin points out, you can simply upgrade pandas using pip:

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
```

Since this version of pandas will be installed in `site-packages` you will, in fact, be at the mercy of any automatic updates to packages within that directory. It's wise to install the versions of packages you want into a [virtual environment](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) so you have a consistent working environment with the bonus of reproducibility.

To answer your last question, the reason Pandas won't "upgrade" to 0.11.0 using `apt-get update` is that packages (of Pandas) from your distribution lag behind or haven't been created yet.

Comment: Thanks Nitin for the original answer... I'm going with Kyle's as his answer and comment were more helpful.  Thanks Kyle.

Answer (score 7):

"pip install --upgrade pandas"  did not work for me on a fresh Ubuntu: 12.04.2 LTS Desktop instance. Within Python, pandas was still showing version  0.7.0.

Instead, I was able to get the update through by using easy install:

```
sudo easy_install -U pandas
```

Answer (score 6):

Try upgrading with pip, like so

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
```

Comment: Nitin - thanks for you reply - much appreciated.  Ran pip as per above - got pages and pages of C compiler warnings, including permission errors.  Tried it again with "sudo"... still got LOTS (many pages) of compiler warnings, but the last line reads "Successfully installed pandas python-dateutil pytz numpy six /n Cleaning up...".  Executing "pandas.__version__" in Python is now showing 0.11.0!  Do you think I'm good to go?  Does pip typically kick out tons of compiler warnings like that?

Comment: Pandas, numpy, scipy, and the rest of the scientific computing stack are going to look rather noisy as they are building packages. I would go ahead and test some code out, but you're probably good to go.