# Broken Pandas Installation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am having problems importing pandas, but don't know what enough about the error message to fix it.

How can I get my pandas installation working again?

I am using Anacondas.  And run it in the py33 environment, rather than the default 2.x environment.

I have tried pip install --upgrade pandas.  But it has not helped.

```
In [17]: import pandas as pd
DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-af55e7023913> in <module>()
----> 1 import pandas as pd

C:\Anaconda\envs\py33\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in <module>()
      4
      5 try:
----> 6     from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
      7 except Exception:  # pragma: no cover
      8     import sys

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

In [18]:
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Anaconda **you shouldn't upgrade using pip**, you should **use conda**:

```
conda update pandas
```

*That's kindof [the whole point of using Anaconda](http://www.continuum.io/blog/conda)! :)*

Comment: I guess worth noting that you can install/upgrade other python packages via pip (**provided you've installed pip via conda**), but you should only do this if the package isn't available in conda. Conda takes care of all the mundane but sensitive requirements stuff for you, let it!

Comment: I agree that the bold print here is a bit over the top. It is explicitly stated in the conda docs that installs via pip are okay. And the restriction to conda's pip only comes from having the paths correctly set automatically, there's nothing inherently wrong using a different pip.

Comment: @K.-MichaelAye whilst this is true, IMO it defeats the purpose of conda and potentially you're going to end up fighting the errors Anaconda was built to avert... so yes, use pip but only if it's not in conda.

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix:

```
sudo easy_install -U pandas
```

it was here:

[Python pandas stuck at version 0.7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759128/python-pandas-stuck-at-version-0-7-0)

Comment: I would be wary with this solution, you may end up updating across all environments and most likely will break stuff. Also, one of the benefits of Anaconda is that you don't need sudo!

Comment: plus: easy_install does not offer uninstall, while pip does. But seriously, almost always the best features of pandas are in the github master, so I would spend 15 minutes on how to install that into my conda distribution.It's really simple once conda is correctly setup.