# python upgrade pandas from 0.14.1 to 0.15.1

Tags: python, pandas, installation, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade pandas (Windows 8) after recently installed anaconda.
I tried it via Pycharm IDE and via command line (pip install -U pandas)
both failed with a long list of tracebacks where in the end :

```
 Command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\use
 rs\\admini~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\2\\pip_build_Administrator\\pandas\\setup.py
 ';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n',
 '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp
 \2\pip-dllk4a-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --co
 mpile failed with error code 1 in c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\2\pip_bui
 ld_Administrator\pandas
 Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\Administrator\pip\pip.log
```

Any ideas how to workaround and upgrade to latest version?

Comment: Is there any specific reason, why you try to update pandas with `pip` and not with `conda`?

Comment: the only reason is that I'm new to python. Should I use conda ?

Comment: Yes, since you are using `anaconda` updating packages with the shipped package manager `conda` is probably the easiest way. `conda install pandas` should work for you.

Comment: @user4045430  `sudo pip install --upgrade pandas` this should do the work
[previous post on the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759128/python-pandas-stuck-at-version-0-7-0)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using anaconda python, then use the `conda` tool to upgrade scientific packages like `pandas`, this is what it is good at.

[Have some documentation on it](http://conda.pydata.org/)